# Dynamic buttons of UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

for my app I am using Facebook connect to share something from my app to Facebook
now for Facebook connect . i use UIACtion Sheet . 
i want change the title of Log in and log out buttons . it means if user log in the facebook my button title change into @"Log Out" and when user is logout title change to @"Log in "

```
- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {

    //change title to Log Out

}

- (void)sessionDidLogout:(FBSession*)session {

    //change title to Log In 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/buttonTitleAtIndex:) in your init or viewDidLoad function then default the value to Login

in your session didLogin function change the

[buttonTitleAtIndex](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/buttonTitleAtIndex:) to Log Out

Similarly do the same for sessioniDidLogout

> buttonTitleAtIndex:
>
> Returns the title of the button at the
>   given index.
>
> - (NSString *)buttonTitleAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
>     Parameters
>
> buttonIndex
>
> ```
> The index of the button. The button indices start at 0.
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> The title of the button specified by
>   index buttonIndex.

Don't forget to release your UIActionSheet in your dealloc function since you'll be doing [alloc] in the init or viewDidLoad function.